# Split overloaded [cas] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I've just noticed that the tag wiki for the [cas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cas) tag is overloaded to apply to both [Central Authentication Service](https://github.com/Jasig/cas) and [Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> The Central Authentication Service (CAS) is a single sign-on protocol for the web. Its purpose is to permit a user to access multiple applications while providing their credentials (such as userid and password) only once. It also allows web applications to authenticate users without gaining access to a user's security credentials, such as a password.
>
> Code Access Security (CAS) is a Microsoft .NET technology for controlling permissions and limiting actions that untrusted code can perform. It allows a hosting environment to, for example, limit file system access based on the publisher of an assembly.

The tag has over 1200 questions, and almost all of them seem to be referring to Central Authentication Service. Should a separate tag be created for [code-access-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-access-security), and how should the retagging be approached if so?

Comment: The best way to disambiguate two tags, is to make sure neither of the resultant tags are ambiguous.

Comment: Ok. So, should we burninate [tag:cas] and move all questions to [tag:code-access-security] or [tag:central-authentication-service] as appropriate? Or what would be the best choice?

Comment: Probably, other option is that maybe we don't need one or both of them.

Comment: [tag:code-access-security] has 315 questions now

Comment: Shouldn't the [cas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cas) tag's info now change, to inform that for `code-access-security` there exists a new tag? Otherwise how can someone start replacing cas with central-access-security on questions?